# Apply stereotype to an InstanceSpecification

Tags: uml, tool-uml

is it possible to Apply stereotypes to an InstanceSpecification?
I'm using Papyrus.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because Papyrus  is not directly working on the UML2 metamodel but using transformation stages with GMF and then apply EMF.
This is what has been explained to me by Omondo support which claims they are the only one in the world to provide such a technology !!

I think you can also ask a question on the Papyrus forum at : http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=121&S=83c3e18bc76d875b479e4901335332ce